# Parameter based branching

Tags: python

Let's suppose I have to branch depending on the parameter passed to the function:

```
def args_func(foo=None, bar=None):
    if foo:
        print foo
    else:
        print baz

args_func(foo='foobarbaz')
```

Is this the only way to branch on this context? This is because the else clause is ambiguous whereas the if clause is very specific with it's conditional ("if foo is true") and since I only have two possible parameters following the zen of python, explicit is better than implicit.

Maybe if/else is not the right construct for this task?

Comment: Have two separate functions instead?

Comment: No, this will be the backend to an ajax call, I want to have the same function receiving the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the else clause is ambiguous

Then let's make it not ambiguous:

```
def args_func(foo=None, bar=None):
    if foo:
        print foo
    elif bar:
        print bar
    # Add elif's here for other arguments
    else:
        raise ValueError("no arguments given")
```

This assumes that `daz` was a typo.

If you're looking for something other than this primitive answer, you're going to need to give a more realistic example of what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Fixed the typo. 
I think your proposal is simple yet very concise. Nothing too fancy here but to write clearer code.